# Here map 3.3. How to get current user position street name?

Tags: android, here-api, street-address

I am using android HERE sdk 3.3.0. I've find current location by using `PositioningManager` then `onPositionUpdated` triggered

```
 public void onPositionUpdated(PositioningManager.LocationMethod method,GeoPosition position,boolean isMapMatched)
 {
     map.setCenter(position.getCoordinate(),Map.Animation.NONE);
 }
```

After this method I want to get street name which user stand. how can i get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please call [PositioningManager#getRoadElement()](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-common-positioningmanager.html#topic-apiref__getroadelement-void), it will return the current map matched street name.

Comment: Hi, i've tried this one. When i got coordinates i would like to display name, but it returns empty name in my case (but i saw street name's on the map)

Comment: How about after waiting and moving a bit. The map matcher may not have locked or found a match for the position yet.