# HERE Maps: show street names on map

Tags: android, here-api

I got some feedback that it wasn't really possible to see street names on the map during navigation. Is there a way to make them more visible? It seems like if I play with the zoom level and tilt I can sometimes see them.

EDIT: It looks as if the other solution attempts to get the street name of a particular road. I would like the map to display side streets along the route during navigation.

EDIT: Screenshot:
[image: with NORMAL_DAY navigation]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Here map 3.3. How to get current user position street name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298630/here-map-3-3-how-to-get-current-user-position-street-name)

Comment: uhh...at first glance that doesn't looked related. They are complaining they can see the names of side streets along the route. This makes it harder to know when to turn. In my simulations I see that the street names only occasionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually by design in the map scheme. Try to change the scheme from the navigation one back to normal day.

Comment: Hmm...doesn't seem to work. Just to be clear do you mean m_map.setMapScheme(NORMAL_DAY)  where m_map is a Map object?

Comment: I added a screenshot.

Comment: Hmmm, I did not expect it to be as bare as the screenshot. I'll have to check internally.

Comment: But just to clarify, it is expected to render less labels.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: did you end finding anything internally?

Comment: Sorry, I never got a chance to reply. At least in our testing we did not see such a phenomenon. When a route is added and in guidance mode the visible street names are restricted to the streets that are part of the route and also have intersections with the route.

Also, can you please let me know where the picture was from? Lat / Long