# HERE Maps SDK: How to show more street names on map

Tags: android, here-api

In understand an algorithm determines at what zoom level we see the name of streets/roads of a certain size/importance. I want to see more street names at a certain zoom level.

My users complain they have to zoom in too much to see nearby street names and frankly, there could be more names displayed without it being too cluttered.

I have customized my layers to reduce clutter and the `LABEL_STREET_CATEGORY_X` are all on. I also tried various map schemes (as suggested here [HERE Maps: show street names on map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41941294/here-maps-show-street-names-on-map)) without success and `TRUCKNAV_DAY` is the prefered. But I couldn't find a "detail level" setting the would show more street names for a lower zoom value.

Answer (score 0):

This is pre-defined  for the map tiles and cannot be customized. We have here a test page where you can test all available options: https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/mrs_options
Hope this helps.